# check if div has loaded completely ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a div called `#pageToLoad`. The page formPage.php loads a form in that div. I need to know if that page is completely load in the div. So that in case of any kind of error I can reset the form using;

```
$("#form").reset();
```

How can i create an event?

```
$("#pageToLoad").load("formPage.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register in `$.ajax( complete:function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)){});` and check the textStatus value. if ok, then load the data into the destination `$('selector')` yourself

```
$.get("formPage.php").success(
    function(response, status, jqXhr){
       alert("Success!");
    }).error(function (response, status, jqXhr){
       alert("These is error.");
    }).complete(function (response, status, jqXhr){
       alert("Complete!");
    });
```

OR

```
$( "#pageToLoad" ).load( "formPage.php", function( response, status, xhr ) {
if ( status == "error" ) {
var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
$( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#pageToLoad").load("formPage.php", function( response, status, xhr ) {

if ( status == "error" ) {
     // "Sorry but there was an error: ";

}
else{
       $("#form").reset();
}
});
```